# Definition of "separate" in Diestels‘s Graph Theory

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology, graph-connectivity

In Dietels [Graph theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-53622-3), he defined "separate" in chapter 1.4 as

> If $A, B \subseteq V$ and $X \subseteq V \cup E$ are such that every $A-B$ path in $G$ contains a vertex or an edge from $X$, we say that $X$ separates the sets $A$ and $B$ in $G$. Note that this implies $A \cap B \subseteq X$.

So vertex in A or B is allowed to be in X? However, in chapter 3.3, he stated the following theorem:

> A set of $a-B$ paths is called an $a-B$ fan if any two of the paths have only $a$ in common.
> Corollary 3.3.4. For $B \subseteq V$ and $a \in V \backslash B$, the minimum number of vertices separating $a$ from $B$ in $G$ is equal to the maximum number of paths forming an $a-B$ fan in $G$.

Here is the contradiction: isn't {a} itself a separator of $a$ and B? Which makes the corollary wrong in most cases.
This is such a fundamental and important concept yet I can't find explicit explanation in the book, could someone clarify it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What Diestel is doing here is not standard; most treatments simply do not allow the case $A \cap B \ne \varnothing$. It makes some theorems a bit simpler or a bit stronger: for example, the proof of this corollary in Diestel reads "apply Menger's theorem to $N(a)$ and $B$" and this would ordinarily need to be qualified if $a$ had neighbors in $B$. The downside is that it's easy to make mistakes in the statements, like here.

My version of Diestel's *Graph Theory* (an electronic version of the third edition) has

> **Corollary 3.3.4.** For $B \subseteq V$ and $a \in V \smallsetminus B$, the minimum number of vertices $\ne a$ separating $a$ from $B$ in $G$ is equal to the maximum number of paths forming an $a{-}B$ fan in $G$.

Note the extra qualifier "$\ne a$" which addresses your concern.

Comment: So it is an abuse of terminology right? Are there more of this in the later contents of the book?

Comment: I wouldn't call it an abuse of terminology; it is simply a different choice of definitions from what most people use. Mostly, you should be aware that it can lead to confusion when reading about Menger's theorem and related topics from other sources. (I would also be careful reading Diestel's defintions related to planar graphs, but I'm not aware of other unusual choices.)

Comment: There is a similar question to yours [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75106), which is resolved by carefully looking at Diestel's definitions.